# increase count of for loop only when condition matches

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I m new to coding,im using a for loop in my project,what i want is to increase the count of for loop only when my conditions matched otherwise for loop should start from the old index.
Any help please!!!

```
if let countEvent = arrEvent?.count{
        for  i in 0..<countEvent{
            let strStartDate = arrEvent![i]["start_date"].string
            let  dateStart = dateFormatter .date(from: strStartDate!)

            let strEndDate = arrEvent![i]["end_date"].string
            let dateEnd = dateFormatter .date(from: strEndDate!)


            if strCurrentDate == strStartDate{
               //increase count of for loop now
            }else{
               //do not want to increase count of for loop now
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First: show your current code ... please take the time and understand what a [mcve] is and why  it is needed.

Comment: Added code now @Felix

Comment: @user3386109 can u plz take a look on that

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen. When you say *"// increase count"*, what variable are you talking about? Is it `i`, `countEvent` or something else?

Comment: its i,I need to increase i when condition meets otherwise loop should starts from old value

Comment: If the iterator is not incremented, you will be processing the same item again and your loop would never end. Your logic is flawed.

Comment: @ Sulthan im using a calendar which is having delegate method of event which called for all dates in a month,if i iterator will be incremented without the matching the condition then my startdate value will be from wrong index in array

Comment: @iOS_developer You are not explaining the problem well.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop implicitly increments its iterator. If you want to gain explicit control over the iterator you could replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop, like this:

```
var i = 0
while i < countEvent {
    //...
    i += 1
}
```

This easily gives you the opportunity to wrap the increment statement in an `if` clause to achieve the conditional incrementing behaviour you are looking for.

Again, as @Sulthan mentioned, if you don’t increase chances are you run into an endless loop. It appears as if you would either have to change your whole logic or at least add another termination condition to eventually end the otherwise endless loop.